# Touchpad click feature fails on login to XP

Tags: windows-xp, touchpad, hp-pavilion

I have an HP pavilion zd7005qv laptop, dual booted with XP Pro and Ubuntu 10.04. The tap to click feature on the touchpad works in Ubuntu and on the log in screen in XP but as soon as I am logged in to XP it ceases to function. Everything else on the touchpad works fine; scrolling, the L/R buttons themselves, etc.

No missing drivers appear in Device Manager.

Any ideas?

Comment: I wish tap to click had voluntarily ceased to function with my touch pad.

Comment: The tap-to-click feature might have been somehow turned off for your user account.  That would explain why it works at the logon screen but stops working when you're logged in.  Go to the Mouse section in the Control Panel to turn it back on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Patches has mentioned in the comments, double-check the Mouse settings in Control Panel after you've logged in.  The feature may have just been disabled inadvertently on you profile.  Another way to check this is to try logging in as a different user (if available) and see if the problem exists under their profile.

Aside from that, try installing a fresh copy of the drivers from HP's website.

Comment: Apparently there are two driver sets on HP's site and the newer one, the one I had installed, jacks up the pad. I uninstalled it and installed the older one and I'm all good. Thank you.

Comment: @winarm - Glad to help.  When stuff on your touchpad stops working, you should almost *always* suspect the drivers first.  I've seen updates break stuff all the time.